# In async Rust, how to I implement a wrapper around poll?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, future

Suppose I have an async function `foo` that returns some value. The value returned is different after each call (this could be e.g. something that reads chunks of data from a file or a random number generator).

I want to implement a wrapper struct around `foo` that implements [`AsyncRead`](https://docs.rs/futures-preview/0.3.0-alpha.10/futures/io/trait.AsyncRead.html). The wrapper reads the values from `foo`, processes them in some way, and then places them into the user-supplied buffer.

Here's what I've tried:

```rust
use futures::io::AsyncRead;
use pin_utils::pin_mut;
use std::io;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::Context;
use std::task::Poll;

async fn foo() -> u8 {
    b'x'
}

pub struct FooReader;

impl AsyncRead for FooReader {
    fn poll_read(self: Pin<&mut Self>, ctx: &mut Context<'_>, buf: &mut [u8])
        -> Poll<io::Result<usize>> 
    {
        if buf.is_empty() {
            return Poll::Ready(Ok(0));
        }
        match foo().poll() {  // << problem here
            Poll::Ready(byte) => {
                buf[0] = byte;
                Poll::Ready(Ok(1))
            },
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
        }
    }
}
```

[(Link to Playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=46b390530f7d0c89c97df4a97a488e11)

This obviously doesn't compile because `poll()` wants a pinned value. Now, **how do I pin the future returned by `foo`?** I tried various combinations of `Box::pin`, `Pin::new` and `pin_mut!` but none of them worked.

Also, **am I supposed to store the `Future` in my struct `FooReader` until it's ready?** Or am I free to drop it after each call, even if it's pending?

---

**EDIT:** The following works:

```rust
let mut future: Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = u8>>> = Box::pin(foo());
match future.as_mut().poll(ctx) {
    ...
}
```

[(Link to Playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a4f0ff8e7f708c6f58610601fb61ef03)

For some reason I have to give `future` an explicit type annotation, otherwise it doesn't compile (somehow the compiler is making confusion between `impl Future` and `dyn Future`).

Even if it works, I would still like to know if this is the "official" way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the `Future` trait is not in the standard prelude, so you have to `use` it before calling the function (the hint is there, buried between all the other compiler errors):

```
use std::future::Future;
```

Then, yes, you must pin the future before use. The easiest way in your case is with `pin_mut!`, that uses a funny syntax:

```
let f = foo();
pin_mut!(f);
```

Now, you can call `poll()`, but remember that you must forward your `Context` argument:

```
match f.poll(ctx) {
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=46b390530f7d0c89c97df4a97a488e11) with working code.

About storing the future or dropping it, you can do whatever you want, that depends on the exact semantics. I personally would expect you to keep the future and run it to completion unless there is something in the documentation that explicitly says otherwise.

Naturally, if you store the future in your struct, `pin_mut!` will not work because it consumes its argument. You need to either keep it in a `Pin<Box>`, or *project* the pin from `self`, since it is already pinned.

To keep the `Pin<Box>` you do something like:

```
pub struct FooReader {
    f: Option<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=u8>>>>,
}
```

And then to use it do not forget the `Box::as_mut()` since you need a `Pin<&mut Future>`, not a `Pin<Box<impl Future>>`:

```
        let f = foo();
        self.f = Some(Box::pin(f)); //remember to declare (mut self) above!
        match self.f.as_mut().unwrap().as_mut().poll(ctx) {
```

You'll probably want to check `self.f` before calling `foo()` again, but you get the idea.

The option of the *pin projection* is nicer because you avoid the extra allocation for the *Box*, but it is more complex and requires extra crates or a bit of unsafe code. If you are really interested I think it deserves a new question on its own.

Comment: How can I use pin projections when the return type of `foo` is an `impl Future`? That's a type that I cannot express in my field declaration, hence I would be forced to use a `Box`

Comment: @user16538: You are right, you cannot do that if you call `foo()` from inside `poll`. I was assuming that maybe your real code took that value from outside `FooReader` and then you could make the whole struct generic over that type. `FooReader<F: Future>`.